Removing a dependency to .NET Framework 4.7.2
I am building a Class Library that targets .NET 8.0. I am creating it using a Wizard in Visual Studio 2022, using C++. The project properties do confirm that the .NET version is 8.0.
Anyway, when I include the .DLL file in a Setup project, Visual Studio detects a dependency to the .NET Framework 4.7.2, which my customer does not want.
Note that this occurs even if the project is empty.
What is the reason? Can I remove this dependency?



It seems like your problem is really similar to this one: Changing .NET framework 4.7.2 to .NET Core 6.0 for a C++/CLI project, try to follow its accepted answer and other related questions like C++/CLI targetting .NET Core 3.1, hope it can help

@Mikk: thanks but I am not migrating a project. I create a project from scratch, making it .NET 8.0 compatible upfront. Trouble is the unwanted dependency to .NET Framework 4.7.2.

The setup project feature was removed from VS a long time ago and is no longer being maintained.  No dedicated support whatsoever for .NETCore/.NET 5+.  It is just a launch condition, not a dependency, it is not going to cause trouble on a reasonably maintained user machine.

Which .DLL did you include in your project? Maybe this library needs .NET Framework 4.7.2

The empty class library. Why does it require 4.7.2?
